# How can I get pending transactions from ethereum mempool faster than others?

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions, txpool

everybody.
I want to get pending transactions faster than others. I have heard I have to use private light node to do it. Is that right? How can I do that? I can also use infura or alchemy but I think using own ethereum node is faster than it. Please help me, if you know about that.
Thanks for your kind attention to my question.